# let tab do every thing in vim

Tags: vim

what i am trying to do is let the `<tab>` do everything.

1. add normal tab if blank space there
2. move up and down in popup menu if it shows up
3. add the return result of CodeComplete() function there

I get the results from the CodeComplete() function to the variable `codecompl`. so problem is here: how to insert the stings in the variable `codecompl`. please don't call return since i have to other thing after inserting the strings of the variable `codecompl`.
Code posts here:

```
function! CleverTab()
    if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
        return "\<Tab>"
    endif
    if pumvisible()
        return "\<C-N>"
    endif
    let s:codecompl = CodeComplete()
    <c-r>=s:codecompl<cr>
    "exec " " .s:codecompl. "\<enter>"."."
    "if g:swith_region_flag == 1
    "    return SwitchRegion()
    "else return s:codecompl
    return ''
endfunction
```

i tried many ways, but the issue still not fixed. and what i think now is to use = to insert the string in variable codecompl. And then do other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you can't just

```
:return s:codecompl
```

because you need other code executed, but *after* the insertion of the contents of `s:codecompl` is done?!

That sequence is impossible to achieve in a single function; move the additional code to a different function and append its invocation to the inserted code:

```
:return s:codecompl . "\<C-O>:call SecondPart()\<CR>"
```

or alternatively

```
:return s:codecompl . "\<C-R>=SecondPart()\<CR>"
```

Comment: it sounds nice and i will get a try. Plus, how about "<c-r>="? it is possible to use it to just insert the string? and why it "<c-r>=s:codecompl<cr>" doesn't work? and the information "E488: Trailing characters" pops up?

Comment: You cannot return a script-local `s:...` variable, as it cannot be evaluated outside the script context!

Comment: make sense. and now, i have the last question that is why i am in Ex mode not insert mode since when i am typing <tab> in an document i am in the insert mode for sure?

Comment: i mean why i am in Ex mode when i am typing <tab> that trigger the CleverTab() func. From what i think, at the moment typing <tab>, i should be in insert mode. that would be very kind of you to help clarify it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, how do you trigger `CleverTab()`? It cannot be done from insert mode directly, because (by definition) every key is inserted literally. You're already breaking out of insert mode via `<C-r>=`; though it's subtle.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not insist on writing your own function, check out [supertab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) . It comes with all these features...

Comment: thanks for you reply. actually, i have Youcompleteme, code_complete and snipmate plugins. and i want all of them works gracefully.